# Primefaces ring items are superposed on each other when placed into a tabView

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, tabview

I have an xhtml page where I have put one `<p:tabView>` containing 3 `<p:tab>`.

In each `<p:tab>` I have one `<p:ring>`. Like this:

```
<p:tabView>
    <p:tab id="tab1">
       <p:ring/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab2">
       <p:ring/>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab id="tab3">
       <p:ring/>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

The ring of the first tab (tab1) is displaying normally.. but for the 2 others (rings of tab2 and tab3), **the ring items are displayed one over the other**. And it's only when I click on some of its items that the original disposition is retrieved.

He is a screenshot of the abnormal display:

[image: abnormal display]

and the normal one (obtained when I click on an item):
[image: normal display]

**Is there a problem in the ring combined with the tabView or am I missing something?**

---

**EDIT: **
Here is the code of my xhtml page (the code of one tab actually):

```
<p:tab id="tabExec" title="Exécutable">
                    <p:growl id="displayE" showDetail="true" />

                    <h:form id="formDev">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                            <h:outputText value="Nom de l'exécutable: *" />

                            <p:inputText value="#{developerController.nomLivrable}"
                                label="Nom du livrable" required="true" />


                            <h:outputText value="Exécutable: *" />

                            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                                <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ftpFileUpload.upload}"
                                    description="Sélectionnez un fichier"
                                    update=":BigTabView:displayE :BigTabView:formDev:outFileNameE"
                                    style="margin-right: 20px;" required="true" label="Exécutable" />

                                <h:outputText id="outFileNameE"
                                    value="#{ftpFileUpload.getFileName()}" />
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                                <p:commandButton value="Valider"
                                    actionListener="#{developerController.storeFile(developerController.nomLivrable)}"
                                    update=":BigTabView:displayE :BigTabView:formDevs:historiqueDevsRing"
                                    style="margin-right: 5px;" />
                                <p:commandButton value="Annuler" type="reset" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:form>

                    <h:form id="formDevs">
                        <p:ring id="historiqueDevsRing"
                            value="#{developerController.executableList}" var="exec">

                            <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images/exe.png']}"
                                height="100px" />
                            <p:commandLink value="#{exec.nomlivrable}"
                                actionListener="#{developerController.connectToFtpServer()}"
                                oncomplete="window.open('ftp://#{exec.emplacementlivrable}'); return false;"
                                update=":BigTabView:displayE">
                            </p:commandLink>

                        </p:ring>
                    </h:form>
                </p:tab>
```

Comment: Please nobody knows about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides on the fact that `p:ring` uses `absolute` position. In order to prevent this behavior (not the positioning, the "stacked" ring), you need to implement a `tabChange` event handler as follows, AFTER adding the forms:

```
<body>
  <p:tabView>
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}"/>
    <p:tab id="tab1">
      <h:form>
        <p:ring value="#{bean.list}" var="st">
          <p:outputLabel value="1#{st}"/>
        </p:ring>
      </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab2">
      <h:form>
        <p:ring value="#{bean.list}" var="st">
          <p:outputLabel value="2#{st}"/>
        </p:ring>
      </h:form>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab3">
      <h:form>
        <p:ring value="#{bean.list}" var="st">
          <p:outputLabel value="3#{st}"/>
        </p:ring>
      </h:form>
    </p:tab>            
  </p:tabView>
</body>
```

In your managedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
public class BeanView implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1775631010811130942L;
  private List<String> list; 

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    list.add("e");
  }

  public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event){
    Tab selected = event.getTab();
    for (UIComponent comp : selected.getChildren())
      if (comp instanceof HtmlForm)
        for (UIComponent comp2 : comp.getChildren())
          if (comp2 instanceof Ring){
            //first solution, primefaces update
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(comp2.getClientId());
            //second solution, jquery click
            FacesContext faces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            String separator = UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(faces) + "";
            String usingId = comp2.getClientId().replaceAll(separator, "\\\\\\\\" + separator);
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('#" + usingId + " li').last().click();");

          }   
  }

  public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
  }
```

This example works and the rings get updated on every tab change, the answer is based on the comment OP made.

This however, will bring your `p:ring` into a default state. For example, if my ring contains 5 values as:

```
                        data0 data1 data2 data3 data4
```

the first item displayed on the ring is *data0*. If I select *data3*, change tabs, reopen the same tab with the ring inside then *data0* will be displayed. To prevent this behavior, you need to implement a selection into your managedBean (`f:setPropertyActionListener` is your best bet).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've understood and implemented your solution, but it doesn't work. When I debug, I can see that the condition `comp instanceof Ring` is never true... even for the tabs with a ring

Comment: Maybe because the `p:ring` is always inside a form?

Comment: I've modified the onTabChange method to search deeper for the ring like that `public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
  Tab selected = event.getTab();
  for (UIComponent comp : selected.getChildren())
   if (comp instanceof HtmlForm)
    for (UIComponent compR : comp.getChildren()) {
     if (compR instanceof Ring) {
      RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(compR.getClientId());
     }
    }

 }` 

And know it finds the ring component but it still don't work (ring still "stacked")

Comment: Are you telling me you have a ring inside a form, inside a tab?

Comment: your comment does make it work... I've pasted an example illustrating this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as I said, even with the example I wrote on my comment, it doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm using PF v 4.0, and I can't change it cause it would refract on many other components and I don't have enough time to fix it (I already tired)

Comment: No other suggestion please?

Comment: I just tried it in PF4.0 and it still works. Maybe there's something else in your xhtml that makes a problem somewhere else?

Comment: You mean to update the "formDevs" when changing the tab? I thought about it but I didn't know how to do it (programmatically)

Comment: Can you please try this: `public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event){ Tab selected = event.getTab(); for (UIComponent comp : selected.getChildren()) if (comp instanceof HtmlForm) if (comp.getClientId().contains("formDevs"))    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(comp.getClientId());} `
If it works, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much rion18 for your constant help but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: The trick is that when I click once on the ring, the items take the right position and everything's OK (even if I change the tab and come back to that tab I find the items at the right place)... Can we reproduce the "onClickOnTheRing" action onTabChange (Maybe)?

Comment: Also to be sure I tried this `public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
  Tab selected = event.getTab();
  for (UIComponent comp : selected.getChildren())
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(comp.getClientId());
 }` And it DOESN'T work...

Comment: Oh it works... :) Thank you so much rion18.. but just one more thing please... when the ring contains only one item, that item is still displayed at the bad position. However, if I go to a tab with a ring containing many items and then come back to the first tab (with a ring containing one item), the item comes to the right place... any explanation?

Comment: I've tried and tried but I seem to have no explanation... The only thing that would come to mind is to set the ring with only one item in the tab with index 0.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean by "The only thing that would come to mind is to set the ring with only one item in the tab with index 0"

Comment: every ring may contain only one element. It depends on the data for each user. I can't know in advance the number of items for each ring

Comment: I found a potential solution but it's quite "hacky". Is it possible to create a test object of the class that `executableList` contains instances of? Because programatically, I was able to add a "test" object, simulate the click, then remove it.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand the solution

Comment: Could we discuss this in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57383/primefaces-ring-items-are-superposed-on-each-other-when-placed-into-a-tabview ?